# Wordpress - Is it possible to use the entire menu item text (not just the arrow or other icon) to collapse submenu

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i am using TrendyNews theme for this blog that i made with wordpress.
Most of the fetures work great, but i have i problem with the mobile menu.
Many users don't understand that they need to click on the arrow or icon on the right side of the menu item in order to collapse a submenu. Is there a way to make the entire menu item clickable, so when the user clicks anywhere on the menu item, the submenu collapses?

I have tried to use some plugins, but they did not solve the this issue.

Comment: Yes there is, but we can't help you out without seeing the code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Guys, i managed to find the solution in the meantime, i just added the folowing code for each of the parent elements:                                                                                 $("li#menu-item-1").on("click", function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $("#menu-item-988 > ul").toggleClass("isShow");
});